# Verb for giving others presents when you're happy

Tags: verbs

I am looking for a verb which is used in situations like these:

- I got good grades and then, for example, I give my friends a piece of chocolate for my achievement.
- When the owner of a restaurant is happy he says "The house pays"

Comment: You did well so you decide to *treat* your friends. The restaurant owner would (in Britain) say  *The food's on the house*.

Comment: Even in USA the *drinks are on the house* means the owner or bartender is treating his customers to a free drink.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As W2 suggested, [***treat (to)***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/treat) is the simplest verb that fits:

> 4.0 (treat someone to)
>
> Provide someone with (food, drink, or entertainment) at one’s own
>   expense.
>
> - I got good grades, and **treated** my friends **to** a piece of chocolate for my achievement.
> - When the owner of a restaurant is happy about his success, he    **treats** his customers **to** a free dessert.

***[Spring for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/spring?q=spring%20for#spring__21)*** is a good alternative in the USA:

> 5.0 North American informal Pay for:
>
> - If I get good grades, I'll **spring for** chocolate to celebrate with my friends.
> - When the owner of a restaurant is happy about his success, he **springs for** his customer's dessert.

***pick up the tab*** (or ***check***) also works in a payment situation.

> - For my achievement of good grades, I **picked up my friend's tab** at the pub.
> - The owner of the restaurant **picked up the check** for his 100th customer's meal.

It's less common, but you could also use the word ***[regale](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/regale)***:

> 1.1 Lavishly supply (someone) with food or drink:

It would probably need to be a **big box** of chocolate to warrant *regale* :-)

Answer (score 2):

To [stand](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stand) may be used in the examples you are making:

> - Informal To treat (someone) or pay the cost of (food or drink):
>
>   - She stood him to a drink. We'll stand dinner.

Comment: Wow!  I've *never* heard that before. I assume that's a BrE thing.  How common is it compared to say, "She bought him a drink." or "We'll cover/pick up dinner"?

Comment: Well, I have always used that expression. I think it is fairly common!! Informal: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stand+drinks&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstand%20drinks%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It peaked in the 20's in AmE, late 30's in BrE.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure anyone I know would understand that (I'm a US Midwest native).

Comment: I am not sure that even in the UK, using "stand" with something other than drinking at a bar, or maybe getting the cheque at a restaurant is very idiomatic.   "I'll stand you some chocolate,"  seems nonsensical outside of some sort of ironic context.